# PHP exec to convert all files in directory using ffmpeg

Tags: php, directory, ffmpeg, exec

How do i loop thru video files in a directory with extension .flv and use exec to convert each one of them (one at a time ) to mpg using `ffmpeg -i original.avi final.mpg`

While current file is converting, the next filename in the array should wait until exec process is complete before moving on and converting other filename in the array.

I know i can use `scandir($dir)` to make an array of all filenames, then maybe use split to only target `.flv` files. Is this the best way to do it. If i use a while loop to run thru each filename and do an exec on it, how do i make sure exec file is fully converted before moving on to the next file in the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$dir='/path/to/dir';
$bash_commands = 'cd "'. $dir .'"
for i in *.flv; do 
    OUTFILE=$(basename "$i" .flv).mpg
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -f mpg "$OUTFILE"
done';
exec($bash_commands);
```

**BASH code explanation:**

1. The first line changes the current working directory with the command `cd`.
   Refer: [Moving around the filesystem @ tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/using-filesystem.html#USING-FILESYSTEM)
2. The second line starts a for loop that repeats the code inside it, while the `$i` variable contains the name of a file from the current working directory that is of the following pattern: `*.flv`. Each iteration changes the value of `$i` to the next file name in the current working directory.
   Refer: [The for loop @ tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_01.html#sect_09_01) and [Loops @ tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html).
3. The third line assigns the value `$(basename "$i" .flv).mpg` to the variable named `OUTFILE`.
   Refer: [Subshells @ tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#SUBSHELLSREF), [basename @ tlpd.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/filearchiv.html#BASENAMEREF) and [Command Substitution @ tlpd.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html#CSPARENS).
4. The fourth line initiates ffmpeg and tells it to convert the file in `$i` to a file named like `$i`, but with it's suffix changed to "mpg" instead of "flv". (The "suffix change" is done in the third line)
5. The fifth line ends the for loop.

The following should be the PHP equivalent:

```
chdir('/path/to/current/working/dir');
foreach (glob("*.flv") as $filename) {
    $OUTFILE = substr($filename, 0, -3) . 'mpg';
    exec('ffmpeg -i "'.$filename.'" -f mpg "'.$OUTFILE.'"');
}
```

Refer: [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), [chdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) and [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: Thanks, this looks great but i'm not too familiar with linux bash commands. Can you explain how the bash command is working specially the OUTFILE= part. Is the semi colon after *.flv correct. How does the command know to only process one file at a time so ffmpeg is not done on all files at once. Can we do this with pure php

Comment: The bash command solution gave a php syntax error. The php solution worked great. I tried the php solution with a folder that contains 50 videos. I thought by closing the browser window the process of looping thru the videos would be killed, but it ended up converting all 50 videos. Do you know of a simple way around kill the whole process.

Comment: @Pinkie: What is the php syntax error given to you? In order to kill that process, I suggest storing the Process ID (aka PID) of the whole BASH commands solution in the database (by making it a background process and using `$!` to get the PID value) and killing the process when required. But that's a question for another topic (for system admins i think)